# How to find the element whose selection triggered onselectionchange-eventlistener on document?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, contenteditable, event-listener

I have a `contenteditable` table. When selecting a cell either by clicking on it or by moving using the arrow-keys from one to another cell, the `onselectionchange` event of the document will be triggered.

How in the event handling function could I find the cell that was selected?

```
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">
table,td { border: 1px solid black;  }
</style>
<script>
function testDocOnSelectionChange(event) {
    console.log(event); // How to find out which cell triggered the event?
}
function init() {
  document.onselectionchange = testDocOnSelectionChange; // syntax just for testing
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<table id="t" style="width:99%;" contenteditable="true">
<tr><td>one</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `console.log( 'event.target:', event.target )`